# C, Segmentation fault (core dumped) on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: c, ubuntu

I'm learning C and I moved recently from Windows to Linux. I was coding a simple program, getting a recurrent error: **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**.
I've analyzed all the code and realized that the error is caused by this function that reads data from a file:

```
FILE *f_out = fopen("sysdata.txt","r+");
char line[30];
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), f_out) != NULL)
{
    count++;
    if (count == 0)
    {
        if (line != "1") {first_project = true;}
        else {first_project = false;}
    }
}
```

I've searched a bit online: i've not understand the error very well (i'm at the basics of c learning) but i have found [this](https://blog.opstree.com/2019/04/02/resolving-segmentation-fault-core-dumped-in-ubuntu/). It's the only tutorial that can help me, but *i get an error at the last command*: running **sudo dpkg -l | grep ^..r | apt-get purge**. The error is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z5wx.png).

I searched online but nothing. Anyone knows how to solve this problem or how to make work my app without segmentation fault?

Comment: `line != "1"` is always true. To compare C style strings, use `strcmp()` from the C library. This has nothing to do with windows vs linux. It is wrong on both.

Comment: Always check if a file was opened successfully before you try to use the pointer. Seems weird to name a variable `f_out` when you're using it to read from a file. You can name it what you like, but a better name like `f_in` would show intent and help you and others reading the code to know exactly what it is for.

Comment: Do you expect `count` ever to have a negative value at entry to the loop?  Because when it doesn't, the program needs to read a lot of lines from the file before the `count == 0` condition could become true, in light of the preceding `count++`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger count has the default value 0, i use it for verifying what line i'm reading

Comment: @shish, "default value" is not a C concept, but if you expect the value of `count` to be zero on the initial entry to your loop then the most likely result of the code presented is that the whole file is read and ignored, with the `first_project` variable retaining whatever value it had beforehand (supposing that the file is opened successfully).

Comment: Following the comment from @RetiredNinja you also open the file in "update" mode, so perhaps there is more to the code than is posted. A fault does not always manifest at the place it was made but can have an apparently unrelated effect. Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with the code presented, but if your segfault arises there then the only plausible explanation is that the `fopen()` is failing, probably because there is no file with the designated name in the program's working directory.  `fopen()` returns a null pointer on failure, and it is the program's responsibility to check for that before attempting to use the result with I/O functions.  If you do try to use a null pointer with `fgets()` then a segfault is a likely outcome.

That is approximately as true on Windows as on Linux, though I believe the Windows terminology differs a bit.  However, it may be that your unfamiliarity with Linux is contributing to a misunderstanding of what the program's working directory is for your test runs.

Answer (score 0):

A segmentation fault, commonly known as segfault, occurs when your program wants to access a memory address outside of your program's allocated memory region.
It means that you can get a segfault by for example reading outside array's bounderies.

However segfault here is not a direct cause of the problems. The segfault occurs internally within the *fgets* function. This is because the file handler might be NULL, meaning that it didn't open succesfully. What your code needs is a small check to ensure the *f_out* is not NULL.

```c
if (f_out == NULL)
{
   puts("file could not be opened");
   return 1;
}
```

Add this just after you open the file and you should be fine.